# REST API retrieving posts from www.sitename.com/category/news/ instead of just just from www.sitename.com

Tags: rest-api

I look a bit thorough some of the previously asked questions and stumbled upon `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?slug=news` (and other permutations) but it doesn't turn anything up. I'm kind of stuck on how to get posts for each category. I looked at `/wp-json/wp/v2/` for trying to get a grasp on how routes work and looked at categories, but couldn't figure it out. I also checked out `/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=news` but it just ends up being the same post no matter what I change the category name to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve posts, you need to use the posts endpoint for starters, not pages. So that's `wp-json/wp/v2/posts`. The documentation for that endpoint is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/).

As you can see in the documentation, under *List Posts*, you can retrieve posts for a specific category using the `categories` argument. However, you need to use the category *ID*, not the slug.

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=14
```

If you absolutely must use the slug, then you need to retrieve that first, from the [categories endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#list-categories):

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/?slug=news
```

That will retrieve any categories with `news` as the slug. This response will include the category ID which you can store and use to query posts with that category.

Comment: Thanks!!! That worked perfectly :) I'll be sure to check out the documentation for endpoints.